# How do I assign a user to the center element of an array first? Assign seats in this order, 3C,3B,3A,3E

Tags: arrays

If I have a 2d jagged array, setup to represent seats in a theater. How do I assign users to the first empty seat towards the center of their chosen row. For example, If I chose row 3, seats available are 3A, 3B, 3C, 3E. I want to assign myself 3C because its the first empty seat toward the center

```
String[][] theater = {{"1A"}, {"2A", "2B", "Tom"},
       {"3A", "3B", "3C", "Ben", "3E"},
       {"4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", "4G"},
       {"Rachel", "Ella", "5C", "5D", "5E", "Sam", "5G", "5H", "5I"}
    };
//This is the jagged 2d array.
```

I am getting an error, that assigns the first empty seat starting from the left, for example 3A, not 3C.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mid = Math.ceil(arr[row].length/2);
boolean flag=false;

if(isAvailable(theater[row][mid])
{ 
     allocate(theater[row][mid-i]);
     flag=true; 
}

for(int i=1; i<mid && !flag; i++)
{
   if(isAvailable(theater[row][mid-i])
   { 
     allocate(theater[row][mid-i]);
     flag=true; 
     break;
   }
   else(isAvailable(theater[row][mid+i])
   {
     allocate(theater[row][mid-i]); 
     flag=true;
     break;
   }
}

if(!flag)
{
  System.out.println("No Seats are available in the given row");
}
```

In this, if the number of seats are even in a row then left seat will be given more priority over the right one. If you want to have the right one more priority then just switch the if-else condition.